# Trying to figuring out to capitalize the the first letter of every string as an input

Tags: c

```
printf("Please enter your fullname: \n");
string s = GetString();
if (s != NULL) {
    for (int i = 0, n = (int) strlen(s); i < n; i++) {
        if (islower(s[i])) {
            toupper(s[i]);
        }
        if (i == 0 || isspace(s[i] - 1)) {
            printf("%c", (s[i]));
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Input: Zamyla Chan
Correct Output: ZC
My program output: Z

Please just explain me in pseudocodes what to do next.So that I can capitalize the first letter of the last name.

Comment: You might have to use : `isspace(s[i - 1])`  inside your last if statement.

Comment: thanks ntsh thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Look at this part of your code,

```
 if(i == 0 || isspace(s[i] - 1))
```

Here, `s[i]` is the `i`<sup>th</sup> character of your string `s`. `s[i] - 1` is subtracting `1` from the character `s[i]` itself. You are then checking if that character is a space.

What you want to do is check if the `i - 1`<sup>th</sup> character is a space. To do that, you will do something like,

```
 if(i == 0 || isspace(s[i - 1]))
```

Comment: @PiyushKumar My pleasure.